# Find out if $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(3-x^2)^n}$ diverges or converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to see if the following sum converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(3-x^2)^n}$$

We had the intuition that this was a geometric series, therefore we found out the value of $|3-x^2|<1$.

This gives us the solutions $-2<x<-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}<x<2$. These are the values of which the sum should converge. However Wolfram says the series diverges by the geometric test. Any hints?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. Don't trust Wolfram Alpha too much!

Comment: I second Janik. Your argument is correct.

Comment: “Intuition”?! This is objectively a geometric series!

Comment: Wolfram alpha does give the correct result though: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a787670f0f1047d7fbe288763c55ba14

Comment: Strangely, WA returns the correct summation and gives the radius of convergence, and at the same time announces divergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely right

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(3-x^2)^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{r^n}$$

is a geometric series converging for $|r|<1$ to

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{r^n}=\frac1{1-r}-1-r=\frac{r^2}{1-r}=\frac{(x^2-3)^2}{x^2-2}$$